# Is there a simple way to convert a tuple list into a list with single elements and vice versa?

Tags: ocaml

Consider the following list:

```
[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9]
```

Is there a built-in function or similar to change this list to:

```
[(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)]
```

And is there another function which I could use to change it back to:

```
[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9]
```

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve in the first place? [We will probably be able to give a better answer with more context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 3):

Lists and tuples are very different things. Note that your second conversion (from tuple list to list) only works if the tuple's elements are all the same type. Also note that each size of tuple is a different type. So if there was a function that worked for 9-tuples, it wouldn't work for 8-tuples or 10-tuples.

Overall this is a rather strange and ungainly conversion, so there's no standard function for it.